# Does the Browser store the calculated coordinates of a div in accessible variables?

Tags: html, css

If I have a flowing layout (position: static / relative), does the browser store the calculated coordinates (x,y) of a div in properties which can be accessed?

Further, it would suffice if the solution worked with Firefox only. JQuery is unfortunately, not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'native' JavaScript you can do it like that:

```
document.getElementById('yourElement').offsetLeft
document.getElementById('yourElement').offsetTop
```

but you'd probably need to add up few offsets of parent elements depends what `position` is applied.

Comment: Note that that is the coordinates relative to the parent container, which won't give you accurate results in all cases.

Comment: I knew the parent container's coordinates. This was exactly what was needed :)

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed. Unfortunately it's pretty difficult to get that information out reliably due to browser inconsistencies and general ugliness of raw DOM access.

I suggest [jQuery](http://jquery.com), where you might have code like:

```
$('#some_div').offset().top
```

Which will give you the `y` position of the div from the top left of the document.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working on a legacy system and need a quick fix. The system does not include the JQuery files. The good thing is that I only need the system to work with Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

No, however using mootools (and probably jquery) you can say `$(element).getLeft()` or `$(element).getTop()`.

or you could use something like this:

```
function getLeft(obj) {
    return (obj.offsetParent==null ? obj.offsetLeft : obj.offsetLeft + getLeft(obj.offsetParent));
}

function getTop(obj) {
    return (obj.offsetParent==null ? obj.offsetTop : obj.offsetTop + getTop(obj.offsetParent));
}
```